# How to marry PostgreSql wit PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I used to use 'already prepared web environments' (apache + php + some rdbms) like for instance lampp. Now I got machine, where I am memory limited and cannot install something like lammp (it's too big) but I need some web environment. I've already intalled apache (from distro), PHP was installed together with OS (DEBIAN). I installed my favourite rdbms which is PostgreSQL and there is a problem: PHP does't want to work wit postgresql. When I display phpinfo() I can see that notihng is enabled in PDO table.

Now, the question: do I really have to recompile my PHP? PHP documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php) says also: "... If shared object module is available, PostgreSQL module may be loaded using extension directive in php.ini or dl() function".

I tried: extension=pgsql.so but didn't work

Does somebody is able to help? I have been trying to do this for a couple of hours :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On debian you need to install package `php5-pgsql`.  Just try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

(You may end up having to install some dependencies.)